# Toggling button classes and text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change text and icons with jquery. When you click at the button it changes, but when you click the button again it struggles. The icon and the text does not change back to default.

Code behind

```
 string box = "<div class=\"alter-Wrp\"> <div class=\"alert alert-danger {0}\">{1}</div></div>";

        if(count > 0)
            litAlert.Text += String.Format(box);
```

asp.page

```
<button class="btn btn-dangerr btn-lg"  type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell beee"></span>
             <span class="text">Show Alarm</span> </button>
        <asp:Literal ID="litAlert" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Jquery

```
$('.btn-dangerr').click( function(e) {
        var tgl = $('.btn-dangerr');
        var box2 = $('.alter-Wrp');
        var icon = $('.glyphicon');
        var text = $('.text');
        var toggleClass = '.beee';
        icon.addClass('glyphicon-bell');
        text.text('Show Alarm');
        box2.slideToggle(function (){
            if (tgl.hasClass(toggleClass)) {
                icon.removeClass('glyphicon-bell').addClass('glyphicon-fire');
                text.text('Hide Alarm');

            } else  {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $('.btn-dangerr').toggleClass(toggleClass);
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w8Yjz/25/

Comment: At a glance, this looks far more complex than it needs to be. Please explain in words what should happen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w8Yjz/18/

Comment: You can't link to local files in a fiddle. Please click the TidyUp button and follow the suggestions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w8Yjz/25/ I hope it works now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is what you're trying to do:

```
$('.btn-dangerr').click(function (e) {
    $('.alter-Wrp').slideToggle();
    $('.beee').toggleClass('glyphicon-bell glyphicon-fire');
    if ($('.beee').hasClass('glyphicon-fire')) {
        $('.text').text('Hide Alarm');
    } else {
        $('.text').text('Show Alarm');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e43Y3/)